# Pyomo.solvers on anaconda mac Ventura 13.0.1 (22A400)

Tags: solver, pyomo, cbc, glpk

I am facing difficulties to install `pyomo.solvers` for anaconda

I do need `glpk cbc ipopt` for my anaconda
I tried the following but none of them worked

- `conda install -c conda-forge pyomo.solvers conda install -c`
- `conda-forge/label/cf201901" pyomo.solvers conda install -c`
- `conda-forge/label/cf202003" pyomo.solvers`

**Homebrew** was also tested but not working (anaconda can't find the path)

Answer (score 2):

The `pyomo.solvers` conda-forge package is no longer maintained. You can install the solvers you mentioned manually using something like:

```
conda install -c conda-forge glpk coincbc ipopt
```